# Как определить message_id у сообщения бота? vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Представим, что бот отправил сообщение:

```
vk_session.method('messages.send', {'peer_id': peer_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': 0})
```

Как узнать `message_id` этого сообщения?

Comment: Посмотреть что вернулось из метода `vk_session.method`

Comment: @gil9red там просто одно число. это и есть message_id?

Comment: Добавил в ответе, плюс заметил, что у вас рандом не указывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно описанию результата выполнения метода [**messages.send** из API:](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send)

> После успешного выполнения возвращает идентификатор отправленного
> сообщения. Если передан параметр peer_ids, возвращает массив объектов,
> каждый из которых содержит поля:
>
> - peer_id — идентификатор назначения;
> - message_id — идентификатор сообщения;
> - conversation_message_id — идентификатор сообщения в диалоге;
> - error — сообщение об ошибке, если сообщение не было доставлено получателю.

Т.е. у вас это будет так:

```
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
...

message_id = vk_session.method('messages.send', {'peer_id': peer_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': get_random_id()})
```

Comment: Не работает. Выдает `0` вместо `message_id`

Comment: @TheNick-Ник, запрос выполнился, ошибок нет, тут ничего нельзя сказать конкретного. Попробуйте повторить запрос на странице API и посмотрите на результат. Если результат неудовлетворительный, то можно задать вопрос поддержке. Вообще, у меня есть ощущение, что API с messages прикрыто

Comment: уже разобрался: я выполнял запрос в беседе, нужен был доступ к переписке

Comment: Нет, не разобрался: доступа недостаточно. Запрос в беседе выдает нулевой `message_id`.

Comment: @TheNick-Ник, не смогу подсказать, почему API у vk возвращает 0, в документации об этом не написано